# Unable to configure auto-type for BZWBK in Keepass 1.2

Tags: passwords, password-management, keepass

Unable to configure auto-type for BZWBK in Keepass 1.2

BZWBK have this special form for entering password...
(set of small fields - separate for every letter)

Good security measure but how to use KeePass ?

Below problematic password field:

[image of problematic password field](https://i.imgur.com/AYTC9)

Any ideas ? Any solutions ?

Comment: That would require substring extraction from database fields. This has [already been requested](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2067671&group_id=95013&atid=609911), but it is not implemented yet.

Comment: I would still be able to solve such a problem just putting password in the plain form of AutoType, e.g. :
{P}{TAB}{A}{TAB}{S}{TAB}{S}{TAB}{W}{TAB}{O}{TAB}{R}{TAB}{D}{ENTER}

Comment: But then you'd have to change the Auto-Type every time you change the password :\

Comment: BZ WBK bank  (adding as unable to find by google

Answer (score 2):

After entering every letter of password JS moves you to the next small field.
What is required is small extra time between keys being pressed by KeePass.
And this is possible to achieve using {DELAY=120} command in AutoType sequence.

That is the Auto-Type sequeance i am using :

Auto-Type-Window: Logowanie

Auto-Type: {USERNAME}{ENTER}{DELAY 2000}{DELAY=120}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}